# Nginx custom uploads rewrite for WordPress Multisite

Tags: wordpress, nginx, multisite

I have a WordPress multisite setup with subdomains on Nginx.

I'd like upload urls such as this to work...

```
http://mysub.mydomain.com/files/2017/07/myfile.png
```

where the location of the file is...

```
<web root>/wp-content/uploads/sites/xx/2017/07/myfile.png
```

This is the location rule in the Nginx config:

```
location ~ ^/files/(.*)$ {
    try_files /wp-content/uploads/sites/$blogid/$1;
    access_log off; log_not_found off;      expires max;
}
```

It doesn't work and I'm unable to see why.

I have also tried (and numerous variations):

```
location ^~ /files {
    internal;
    alias /www/wp-content/uploads/sites/$blogid;
    access_log off; log_not_found off;      expires max;
}
```

If either of these can be confirmed as 'should work' then I'll start looking at rules higher up my code that may be taking precedence (although nothing's jumped out at me yet)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what did work:

```
if (!-e $request_filename) {
    rewrite ^/files/(.*) /wp-content/uploads/sites/$blogid/$1 last;
}
```